# Only display dates after current date from database in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql

So I have a database, and I am querying it to get a list of events and there dates. I want to change my query to only return the events who have not already occured.

My query at the moment is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select EventID, EventDate, Location from Events";
```

and then it inputs it into my datagridview.

I tried:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select EventID, EventDate, Location from Events Where EventDate > CURDATE()";
```

but it didnt return any dates.

Comment: `CURDATE` isn't a MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an approach for both MSSQL and MySQL since you did not specify which DBMS you are using.

MSSQL:

You can use [GetDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx). This should give you the current date and time.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select EventID, EventDate, Location from Events Where EventDate > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)";
```

MySQL:

You can use the [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function, and truncate the time part casting it to DATE.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select EventID, EventDate, Location from Events Where EventDate > CAST(NOW() AS DATE))";
```